# DatagridView Event To allow Numbers, Backspace & Delete Keys Only VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, vb.net-2010

How to alter the below code to accept **Delete** and **BackSpace** Keys also??

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    Select Case DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
        Case Is = 0, 1
            AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_keyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    If Not (Char.IsDigit(CChar(CStr(e.KeyChar))) Or e.KeyChar = ".") Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**Current Code After Modification** - Not Working

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    Select Case DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
        Case Is = 0, 1
            AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyDown
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_keyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    If Not (Char.IsDigit(CChar(CStr(e.KeyChar))) Or e.KeyChar = ".") Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT - 2 Code**

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing

        Select Case DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
            Case Is = 0, 1
                AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyDown
        End Select

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_keyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
        If Not (Char.IsDigit(CChar(CStr(e.KeyValue))) Or e.KeyValue = ".") Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Now getting error in TextBox_keyDown Word this line...

```
AddressOf TextBox_keyDown
```

**Error Text**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error BC31143 Method 'Private Sub TextBox_keyDown(sender As Object, e
>   As KeyEventArgs)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate
>   'Delegate Sub KeyPressEventHandler(sender As Object, e As
>   KeyPressEventArgs)'.

Comment: You can't do that using the `KeyPress` event. you need the `KeyDown` event instead.

Comment: I changed it in both the places as KeyDown but it's not allowing me to delete the dgv data.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: post your current code and explain what `not allowing` actually means.

Comment: Added the current code above.  Please check and suggest.

Comment: e should be of type `KeyEventArgs`, not `KeyPressEventArgs`.

Comment: The code you posted cannot even compile.

Comment: Updated the post with the revised code.  Still no success since the error pops up in another line.

Comment: And what **is** the error ?!

Comment: `AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyDown, AddressOf TextBox_keyDown`

Comment: Okay, I changed it and that error gone away... But now its allowing all entries Text Number Special Character and all.... This silly thing wasting my time too much... Still No luck...

Comment: It's allowing all type of entries and not allowing Delete Key LOL.  I lost my patience in achieving this task... :(

Comment: Try to implement a `NumericUpDown` column or a `MaskedTextBox` column. [Here](http://www.vb-tips.com/MaskedEditColumn.aspx) is a good link for `MaskedTextBox` column. Also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881(v=vs.80).aspx) is a good link for `NumericUpDownColumn`. Surely you will find more resources if you search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the DataGridview **EditMode** Property to **EditOnEnter** and use the below code.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    Select Case DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
        Case Is = 0, 1
            AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_keyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    If e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow only numbers, backspace, arrow keys, delete, home, end, spacebar in column-1 of the datagridview.

```
private void DGV_Test_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
            if (DGV_Test.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Desired Column
            {
                TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
                if (tb != null)
                {
                    tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);                    
                }
            }
        }

        private void Column1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == 0x20)  // Allow space also
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The problem with code section is that if we want to add/edit multiple rows of datagridview then it doesnt allow so. Can anybody suggest the solution for the same ?